# AFNetworking JSON responseObject has modified formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using AFNetworking to fetch a JSON object :

```
-(void)getData{

    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/service.php"
        parameters:parameters

        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"audio" error:nil];

        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
}
```

The service.php page returns a valid JSON object :

```
 {"song_id": 2, "song_name": "Red Fang - Wires", "confidence": 120, "offset_seconds": 50.3873, "match_time": 1.0025339126586914, "offset": 1085}
```

with a JSON header :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

However here is the output of the responseObject :

```
Success: {
    confidence = 120;
    "match_time" = "1.035004138946533";
    offset = 1085;
    "offset_seconds" = "50.3873";
    "song_id" = 2;
    "song_name" = "Red Fang - Wires";
}
```

The order is changed, and some of the quotes are stripped. Whenever I try to use the values of the responseObject (execpt for "song_name") my app crashes with a

```
 -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You already received good answers. I would only add, that if you would like to work successfully, you should go back and learn a lot basics. In particular, if you have something called "data", never name the getter method "getData" but only "data". This might sound like a nitpicking, but in reality could brake many things like KVO, the entire CoreData stack, etc... Naming conventions are super important in Cocoa (touch)!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I learn everything myself so I'm sure I miss a lot of things. I'm going through Apple docs but it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON-Object everything except the song_name is a NSNumber (which doesn't understand the selector "length"). You can use the selector "stringValue" to convert a NSNumber to NSString.

Something like this:

```
NSString* song_id_str = [responseObject[@"song_id"] stringValue];
```

Or you just use NSNumber

```
NSNumber* song_id = responseObject[@"song_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No problem with responseObject order changes.
2. if objects are NSNumber in responseObject,quotes are stripped response

Problem is, you assigned NSNumber value as NSString, check your responseObject data types and assign correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same "problem" that isn't a problem at all as many people using JSON: You are looking at the output of NSLog, which is *not* the same as the JSON data. It's there for debugging purposes.

You have another problem that is likely because you don't understand what NSDictionary does: In a dictionary, the items are not ordered. In a JSON dictionary, they are not ordered either. The order of items in a JSON dictionary is completely irrelevant. You can't rely on it. You can't reproduce it. That's how dictionaries work.

But if you look at the original JSON data, it should be clear that all the object except song_data are not strings, but numbers. So you can't use them as strings. Since they are numbers, you will receive NSNumber* and you better treat them as numbers. If you really think you need strings (and you don't or the server would have sent you a string), get the objects as NSNumber* and use the stringValue method. Here's how you do it properly if you really want a string:

```
NSString* offset = myDict [@"offset"];
if ([offset isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    offset = [(NSNumber *)offset stringValue];
```